# ActionBar Icon Image not doing anything when clicked?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

I am following the Google API Library for the ActionBar and am not able to get it to navigate back home. There is nothing caught by LogCat....so no errors, but the syntax doesn't allow the navigation.

I will also admit that i don't have much experiences with Actionbar as well.

I don't understand why this is not working and much help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my Activity code here:

```
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MoveContactsActivity extends ListActivity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_move_contacts);
//      getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("My Relocation");
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.menu_ic_launcher);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        final TextView welcomeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WelcomeText);
        final TextView relocationId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.relocationID);
        final TextView addressOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressOne);
        final TextView addressTwo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressTwo);
        final String RelocationId = bundle.getString("UID1");
        relocationId.setText("Your Relocation: #" + RelocationId);
        new contentCall().execute("");

        findViewById(R.id.WebAddressTwo).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.Relocationmw.com");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_move_contacts, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class contentCall extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MoveContactsActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            if (checkNullState() == false) {
                showMyDialog();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String xml = null;
            String calling = "https://demo.relocationmw.com/ws_docmgmt/mobile.asmx/GetRelocationMoveContactsTrim?UserID=";
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            // String UID = bundle.getString("UID");
            String UID = "801";
            String URL = calling + UID;
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
            HttpResponse httpResponse;
            try {
                httpResponse = client.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return xml;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            String xml = result;
            String KEY_ITEM = "Contact";
            String KEY_CONTACTTITLE = "ContactTitle";
            String KEY_NAME = "Name";
            String KEY_MAINPHONE = "Phone";
            String KEY_CELLPHONE = "Cell";
            String KEY_FAX = "Fax";
            String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            Document doc = getDomElement(xml);
            if (xml != null) {
                {
                    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                            map.put(KEY_CONTACTTITLE, getValue(e, KEY_CONTACTTITLE));
                            map.put(KEY_NAME, getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
                            map.put(KEY_MAINPHONE, getValue(e, KEY_MAINPHONE));
                            map.put(KEY_CELLPHONE, getValue(e, KEY_CELLPHONE));
                            map.put(KEY_FAX, getValue(e, KEY_FAX));
                            map.put(KEY_EMAIL, getValue(e, KEY_EMAIL));
                        menuItems.add(map);
                    }

                    String[] hashMapObjects = { KEY_CONTACTTITLE, KEY_NAME,
                            KEY_MAINPHONE, KEY_CELLPHONE, KEY_FAX, KEY_EMAIL };
                    int[] listItemObjects = { R.id.ContactTitle, R.id.Name,
                            R.id.MainPhone, R.id.Cell, R.id.Fax, R.id.Email };
//              ContactListAdapter adapter = new ContactListAdapter(MoveContactsActivity.this, 0, menuItems);
                    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter (MoveContactsActivity.this,menuItems,R.layout.listed_contacts,hashMapObjects, listItemObjects);
                    SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder binder = new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object object,
                                String value) {
                            if(!(view instanceof TextView)){
                                return false;
                            }
                            final TextView text = (TextView) view;
                            text.setVisibility(TextUtils.isEmpty(value) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                            text.setText(value);
                            return true;
                        }
                    };
                    adapter.setViewBinder(binder);
                     setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
                if (checkNullState() == true) {
                    dismissMyDialog();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Map... values) {
    }

    // XML Parsing Start
    public Document getDomElement(String xml) {
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        // return DOM
        return doc;
    }

    public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        return getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }

    public final String getElementValue(Node elem) {
        Node child;
        if (elem != null) {
            if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
                for (child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child
                        .getNextSibling()) {
                    if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                        return child.getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // XML Parsing Stop

    // ProgressDialog Tracking
    private ProgressDialog pd1;
    private boolean isMyDialogShowing;

    boolean checkNullState() {
        boolean test;
        if (pd1 != null) {
            test = true;
        } else {
            test = false;
        }
        return test;
    }

    void showMyDialog() {
        isMyDialogShowing = true;
        pd1 = new ProgressDialog(MoveContactsActivity.this);
        pd1.setTitle("Contacts");
        pd1.setMessage("Loading Contacts....");
        pd1.show();
    }

    void dismissMyDialog() {
        pd1.dismiss();
        isMyDialogShowing = false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Menu XML.....This is where i think the issue is but like i said i am not great with ActionBar yet.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>

</menu
```

>

This is the LogCat Error when i change case to

```
case android.R.id.home:
```

LogCat:

```
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testingapp/com.testingapp.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152):    at com.testingapp.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:50)
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
03-26 13:45:40.666: E/AndroidRuntime(19152):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing worng with Menu or Home.
your problem that you are trying to access a `NULL` object on `onCreate()` function on the `HomeActivity` class.
Check line 50 at HomeActivity.java

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.testingapp.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:50)
```

Comment: That's: final String RelocationId = bundle.getString("UID1");......which is only Null when the intent is triggered to go home on the ActionBAr

Comment: bundle is NULL, you haven’t set any extra before starting the Home Activty, you need to add a check if(null!=bundle){.....} OR put some data in the intent intent.putExtra("UID1", "value"); before starting the activity.

Comment: thanks so much, showed me why and i was able to put alot more into why i didn't check that but i got it fixed and it works wonderfully now thank you!

Answer (score -1):

For me only works this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    // your code goes here...
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);        
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }

    return true;
}
```